# Simulator takes much time to run in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode7

After upgrading to Xcode 7,Simulator loads Everytime with Progress bar and take much time to launch an app.Even its taking a bit more time while building an IPA,compare to previous version of Xcode. Is there any master trick to make my Xcode faster?

Thanks!!

Comment: i think your machine RAM not enough for load all things at a time. so that take long time to load

Comment: As I have mentioned,It was working good in previous version of Xcode but getting slower response after upgrading.So I think machine RAM is not an issue.

Comment: That what @NitinGohel want to say. May be you have to upgrade your RAM because of new simulator.

Comment: it does not mean that working same with new one. osx leopard working smooth but lion not :)

Comment: Check this blog : http://appleinsider.com/articles/15/09/13/apples-xcode-ios-simulator-shows-2gb-ram-for-iphone-6s-6s-plus-4gb-for-ipad-pro

Comment: Okay thanks,any other possibility??